# Reporting Endpoints in LinkedIn Marketing API

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I've been trying to hit the new "versioned" LinkedIn Marketing API in an attempt to pull any kind of analytics on my campaigns. Utilizing the python and requests. Documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http%2Chttp-member-country-above0323%2Chttp-member-country-below0323%2Chttp-member-country-unversioned%2Chttp-memberregion-above0323%2Chttp-memberregion-below0323%2Chttp-memberregion-unversioned%2Chttp-above0323-membercounty%2Chttp-versioned-membercounty%2Chttp-unversion-membercounty).

```
import requests

headers = {
   'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer {TOKEN}',
   'Linkedin-Version': '202303',
}

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&pivot=CAMPAIGN&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=3&dateRange.start.year=2023&timeGranularity=DAILY&fields=pivotValue&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A507920541'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

After a bunch of fighting, I've settled that my closest effort yields this result:

> {'errorDetailType': 'com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest', 'message':
> 'Multiple errors occurred during query param validation. Please see
> errorDetails for more information.', 'errorDetails': {'inputErrors':
> [{'input': {'inputPath': {'fieldPath': 'dateRange.start.day'}},
> 'code': 'QUERY_PARAM_NOT_ALLOWED'}, {'input': {'inputPath':
> {'fieldPath': 'dateRange.start.month'}}, 'code':
> 'QUERY_PARAM_NOT_ALLOWED'}, {'input': {'inputPath': {'fieldPath':
> 'dateRange.start.year'}}, 'code': 'QUERY_PARAM_NOT_ALLOWED'}]},
> 'status': 400}

I do not know what it is looking for for the date range. If change the Linkedin-Version to 202302 I get this error:

> {'status': 403, 'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'code': 'ACCESS_DENIED',
> 'message': 'Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing
> Exception while processing fields [/dateRange.start.day,
> /dateRange.start.month, /dateRange.start.year]'}

Suggestions are very much appreciated.

EDIT

Utilizing postman as was suggested in the comments yielded this:

> {
> "status": 400,
> "code": "ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT",
> "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request"
> }

This was the url, which I think is set up as the old version tbh.

[https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.start.month=3&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2023&dateRange.end.month=03&dateRange.end.day=20&timeGranularity=ALL&accounts=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:507920541&pivots[0]=CAMPAIGN&pivots[1]=CONVERSION&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,externalWebsitePostClickConversions,externalWebsitePostViewConversions,costInLocalCurrency,externalWebsiteConversions,costInLocalCurrency,dateRange,pivotValues](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.start.month=3&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2023&dateRange.end.month=03&dateRange.end.day=20&timeGranularity=ALL&accounts=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:507920541&pivots%5B0%5D=CAMPAIGN&pivots%5B1%5D=CONVERSION&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,externalWebsitePostClickConversions,externalWebsitePostViewConversions,costInLocalCurrency,externalWebsiteConversions,costInLocalCurrency,dateRange,pivotValues)

Comment: In the documentation link you provided, there is a postman collection linked with an orange button right at the top. The postman collection features some examples and suggests that dateRange is given in the following format: dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020),end:(day:30,month:3,year:2020)) https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis/workspace/linkedin-marketing-solutions-versioned-apis/overview I do not have credentials for the linkedin API, so I cannot verify myself.

Comment: Thanks @Bertolt I was on there for two hours yesterday trying to get it to work. Using their setup yielded a 400 error: "Invalid query parameters passed to request" which seems further away than where I was. The URL generated by postman was as such. I've edited above with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where it landed is something like this:

> [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2023&dateRange.end.month=04&dateRange.end.day=17&timeGranularity.value=DAILY&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3AXXXXXXXXX&pivots[0].value=CAMPAIGN&projection[0].value=pivotValues&fields=pivotValues,impressions"](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=statistics&dateRange.start.year=2023&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.end.year=2023&dateRange.end.month=04&dateRange.end.day=17&timeGranularity.value=DAILY&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3AXXXXXXXXX&pivots%5B0%5D.value=CAMPAIGN&projection%5B0%5D.value=pivotValues&fields=pivotValues,impressions%22)

As the URL but I needed to use the 1.0.0 X-Restli-Protocol-Version header (Which might be default). They do not make that clear in their documentation. I also recommend this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version

Which cleared some things up but is not linked from the documentation.